# jQuery equivalent of onLoading callback in Prototype.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I've been using prototype.js for my site for quite some time(it's default option in magento system). The ajax request method of prototype provides an event onLoading in which I show some custom animation on page which is executed once only. Now, we are switching to jQuery completely, leaving prototype behind(No hard feelings to Prototype folks, it's what I have to do!).

For searching quite some time, I couldn't find any similar method in jQuery which works in parallel of the ongoing Ajax request. JQuery gives beforeSend but that works prior to making the Ajax request, not in parallel. ajaxStart method works for all ajax requests and it will kill my goal.

Is there any way out to do that with some work around in jQuery? Any other approach that will get me out of prototype is very welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: So what is your goal? Showing loading animation (only once) while an ajax request is in progress?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/), `onLoading` maps to the `Initialize` stage in the XHR's life cycle. Therefore, it should be equivalent to `beforeSend`.

Comment: Technically it's not a loading animation, it's a animated way to compensate the time slag in ajax request and response by showing user that the process is taking place on his system only, but in the end it's just an animation in parallel, that should be completed before recieving response.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I'm not sure about it, although prototype documentation says it's called after XHR is setup, but jQuery documentation doesn't say anything about when does the beforeSend called. From their name, I concluded, that onLoading should be concurrent to the request sent, and beforeSend is called prior to sending the request.